# Sending POST request with Form params through java don´t get response

Tags: java, rest, httprequest

I'm trying to send a request to a REST Web service through Java.

I need to send some form params to the web service, because they are too big to send by queryParams.

The httpRequest method that sends is the following:

```
public static String sendPostWithParams(String urlParam, Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlParam);

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0)
            postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
    conn.connect(); 

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    // print result
    return response.toString();
}
```

I've tried to send the request through Postman and it works fine, just like expected. But when I try to send the request through Java, I get the two following lines printed in the console, and then it just freezes there until it timeouts.

```
15:18:18,160 INFORMACIÓN [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
15:18:18,170 INFORMACIÓN [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class .com.services.rest.ApplicationConfig$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
```

The web service is not being called, because I have a breakpoint there and it never reaches it.

So I think the problem may be in the way I generated the request through Java, but I haven't found another way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I´ve solved. The way I was sending the request is OK, the service is OK, but I was running JBoss in Debug mode using Eclipse Luna, and that was making it to hang there. So I runned it in run mode, and it works perfectly. So If someone else face it, run in run mode and try. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer, both ways to send post request with form params work fine

Answer (score 0):

**Using `HttpClient`**

```
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("your url");                

            //Set Headers
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //Add Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "kainix"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "google@123"));
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));


            //Sends Request                
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  

            //Read From Response
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader;
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(inputLine);
            }

            System.out.println(result);
```

Try this simple and clear, you will need `httpclient-4.x` and `httpcore-4.x` jar files for this

Comment: Thanks, I will try that,  but isn´t there a way to do it with the already included java.net?. Because I´m already using it to send POST with query params and it´s working fine. thanks

Comment: I'm trying that and in the first line when you do " HttpClient client = new HttpClient();" I get an error that says that can't insatnciate HttpClient.

Comment: my bad its `HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient()`

Comment: But if you've downloaded `HttpClient-4.5 jar` then you may want to use 
`ClosableHttpClient client=HttpClients.createDefault();` since `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated

Comment: @javapai did you try the above thing

Comment: Thanks. I´m trying right now, but I´m getting a ClassNotFoundException in org.apache.http.client.HttpClient. I´ve downloaded and added to the classpath both jars that you pointed above. am I missing something?

Comment: I normally right-click on library folder which is created when I make a new NetBeans project and add jar files, try clean building the project or restart the IDE or even the machine

Comment: @Kanix I hadn´t seen your comment about the deprecated, so I changed and now it´s working until the point it sends, and then it freezes showing in the console the same two lines that I posted in the question. Thanks for the help, but I think the problem wasn´t there.